Type "{ onClick: any; children: any; }" is not valid
Im trying to deploy a NextJS app in github pages, and it fails at building giving the following error:
Failed to compile.

app/components/Button/page.tsx
Type error: Page "app/components/Button/page.tsx" has an invalid "default" export:
  Type "{ onClick: any; children: any; }" is not valid.

This is my button
const StylizedButton = ({ onClick, children }) => {
  return (
    <StyledButton onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </StyledButton>
  );
};

export default StylizedButton;

this is my first time deploying in github and I dont have much experience

you are using typescript, so add type to your component props, try this StylizedButton = ({ onClick, children }:any) 

it working, but its not a real type. to get more details about typing you should learn typescript.
